# Erro ao rodar aplicação web

Tags: java-ee, tomcat

Instalei o Tomcat em um servidor e estou tentando acessar minha aplicação porém sempre da esse erro:

```
The requested resource (/ProjetoAuditoria) is not available.
```

Quando eu Starto na minha máquina outros computadores da rede conseguem acessar, porém quando eu coloco no servidor não funciona. Alguém pode me dizer qual o problema?

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">


    <display-name>Sistema Auditoria</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pages/autenticacao.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Configuração do Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>hot-sneaks </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>

        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>


    <!-- Carregamento do contexto do hibernate -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>br.com.auditoria.util.ContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Quando entro no tomcat manager aparece isso, eu clico em Start e mesmo assim nada acontece.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já verificou no `Tom Cat Manager` se a sua aplicação fez realmente o `deploy` ?

Comment: Olha o que eu fiz foi colocar o war na pasta `webapps` depois executei o `startup.bat` que fica na pasta bin, quando fiz isso uma pasta foi criada com o nome da minha aplicação e com todo conteúdo dentro.

Comment: Entra no `Tom Cat Manager` olha como está o contexto da sua aplicação, só mais uma coisa, poste seu web.xml

Comment: Pronto, editei a pergunta e coloquei uma imagem

Comment: Um pouco mais abaixo existe uma opção para fazer depoy, faça por lá, como mostra na imagem ele não pegou o seu Contexto da aplicação `None specified`

Comment: Pronto fiz o deploy selecionando o `WAR` apareceu a mensagem de ok mas ainda nao está funcionando e continua `None specified`

Comment: Quando tento startar pelo `TomCat Manager` da o mesmo erro `FAIL - Application at context path /ProjetoAuditoria could not be started`

Comment: Olhe o arquivo de logs @Techies não estou conseguindo obter uma resposta certa.

Comment: Olhei e ta dando erro nisso:
`org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class br.com.auditoria.util.ContextListener
 java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: br/com/auditoria/util/ContextListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class br.com.auditoria.util.ContextListener)`

Comment: Esse erro `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class br.com.auditoria.util.ContextListener)` é referente a versão do seu Java, com está configurado sua IDE java/tomcat e no servidor ? provavelmente será isso

Comment: Entendi, o tomcat está na mesma versão, porem o java esta na versão 1.7 no servidor e eu fiz em cima da 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifique a versão instalada no seu servidor, de acordo com o erro apresentado por você a versão instalada é inferior a `J2SE 8 = 52`

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class
>   br.com.auditoria.util.ContextListener)

Abaixo a lista contendo o número e as versões do Java

```
J2SE 8 = 52, J2SE 7 = 51, J2SE 6.0 = 50, J2SE 5.0 = 49, JDK 1.4 = 48, JDK 1.3 = 47,  JDK 1.2 = 46, JDK 1.1 = 45
```

Comment: Entendi, eu tenho que instalar o JRE ou JDK?

Comment: Faça o donwload do JRE + JDK

Comment: Problema resolvido, instalei só a JRE e já deu certo, obrigado.